# php autoload not loading correctly?

Tags: php, class, php-ews

Using php-ews I try to create a calendar event by example (just to get the hang of it):

```
require $server_path.'scripts/ews/vendor/autoload.php';
use garethp\ews\API;
use garethp\ews\API\Enumeration;
use garethp\ews\API\Type;

$ews = API::withUsernameAndPassword($exchange_host, $_SESSION["user_data"]["u_email"], $_SESSION["user_data"]["u_pwd"]);
```

Seems to work without errors.

```
// Start building the request.
$calendar = $ews->getCalendar();

$start = new DateTime('8:00 AM');
$end = new DateTime('9:00 AM');

$request = array(
    'Items' => array(
        'CalendarItem' => array(
            'Start' => $start->format('c'),
            'End' => $end->format('c'),
            'Body' => array(
                'BodyType' => Enumeration\BodyTypeType::HTML,
                '_value' => 'This is <b>the</b> body'
            ),
            'ItemClass' => Enumeration\ItemClassType::APPOINTMENT,
            'Sensitivity' => Enumeration\SensitivityChoicesType::NORMAL,
            'Categories' => array('Testing', 'php-ews'),
            'Importance' => Enumeration\ImportanceChoicesType::NORMAL
        )
    ),
    'SendMeetingInvitations' => Enumeration\CalendarItemCreateOrDeleteOperationType::SEND_TO_NONE
);

$request = Type::buildFromArray($request);
$response = $ews->CreateItem($request);
```

I get:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method garethp\ews\API::CreateItem() in

in the execute part ($ews->CreateItem())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at my [`examples/`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/tree/master/examples), they cover exactly this. The firs thing to note is that creating Calendar events is [incredibly simplified](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/examples/calendar/createItem.php), so your long request isn't entirely needed. That being said, if you want to access the functions directly, you can't do

```
$response = $ews->CreateItem($request);
```

you need to do

```
$response = $ews->getClient()->CreateItem($request);
```

More info on building requests manually can be found [here](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/examples/basic/buildingRequests.php).